# globals visible but content is gone

Tags: c, global-variables

header bs.h

```
#ifndef BS_H
  #define BS_H

  extern int  glob_1;

#endif
```

header og.h

```
#ifndef OG_H
  #define OG_H

  #include < bs.h >

  extern void func_1( void );

#endif
```

func_1

```
#include < og.h >
extern void func_1( void )
{
  int dummy;

   dummy = 22;
   glob_1 += dummy;
}
```

mainfile

```
#include < bs.h > 
#include < og.h >

int glob_1;

int main()
{
  glob_1 = 33;
  func_1();
  return 0;
}
```

I have made a small sample that is structured as i understand how to
declare, define init and share globals among different modules.
But this throws me a lnk2019 error - unresolved symbol glob 1
What is wrong here?

Comment: Could you show us the `func_1()` definition?

Comment: The posted code cannot compile (as far it's c) could you post the code that actually compile?

Comment: glob_1 is a simple int32 that holds the size of a structure.

Comment: @purplepsycho why do you think it won't compile - it does.

Comment: I think that the code will not compile -I assume it's c- because of the `main` function prototype: it should be `int main(void){...}` or `int main(int argc, char*argv[]){...}` but not just `main{...}`. Which compiler do you use? Did you enabled warnings diplay?

Comment: @purplepsycho

yes it is c
the post of the code is just a simplification of the programs structure
i forgot the return value in the posted code

Comment: You might be interested in reading [MCVE], for help us to help you.

Comment: @purplepsycho
thanks for the hint.
I think there is a problem in my misunderstanding the structure.
For some reason the variable exists global and will be erased if i enter another module of the programm.
I am using the intel compiler
I will set up a simple test programm to recreate the problem and then post the whole code.

Comment: functions are always 'extern' unless the 'static' modifier is used, so no need to use the modifier 'extern' on a function

Comment: the header files `bs.h` and `og.h`  are not system headers, so should be included via double quotes, not `<` and `>`

Comment: I ran the posted code (after correcting the `#include` statements and after inserting a `#include <stdio.h>` and the statement `printf( "%d\n", glob_1 );` just before the `return` in `main()`  the resulting output was 55, which is correct.  Please post code that displays the problem.

Comment: @user3629249
if i add an #include "C.\....og.c"  in og.h and take the file og.c out of the solution explorer it works.
If i delete the include statement and add og.c to the solution explorer i get  a LNK 1120 error about func_1
The path that holds all files is named in the additional include directorys option
If i leave the include in og.h and add the file og.c to the solution explorer
i get a "func_1" has already been defined error

Comment: solved the global var problem.
ps -> personal stupidity 
copied a block of the globals from the definition section to the initialising
section and copied the type specifier too.
So they were refined as locals and their content disappears when leaving the function... sorry for bothering you

Comment: Never `#include` a C source file.